# WP CRON duplicate wp_insert_post with has < and > tag

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-cron

When I trigger the CRON job to insert all the MovieTitle, all the MovieTitle with the < and > tag, will insert more duplicates. but if run this through the plugin itself works fine.

Any solution for this really appreciated. Thank you.

```
function process_movie($movie){
    $already_insert = false;
    //check if movie already exist
    $movie_post = get_page_by_title($movie['MovieTitle'],OBJECT,'movieinfo');
    $movie_status =  get_post_status($movie_post->ID);
    if($movie_post->post_title == $movie['MovieTitle']){
        $movie_post_id = $movie_post->ID;
    }
    if( get_page_by_title($movie['MovieTitle'],OBJECT,'movieinfo') && $movie_status != 'trash'){
         $already_insert = true;
        $movie_post_id = $movie_post->ID;
    }
    else{

        $movie_post_id = $this->save_movie($movie);
    }

    return $movie_post_id;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this?